# Counting a String in a list of Strings and convert it into a tuple like [(String, int)] | Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

my question is how to implement this:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

freq :: [String] -> [(String ,Int)]
freq words = []
```

in Haskell. I want to count how many times a specific String occurs in a list of Strings.

Comment: So where do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Look at the functions in Data.Map http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html It will be clearest if you first write `freqMap :: [String] -> Map String Int`

Comment: A little hint where to start would be nice. Just to know what to use...

Comment: @mojo92 Take a look at `Data.Map`, there's several functions in there that can update or insert keys in the `Map`, so it should be pretty straightforward to implement this.  Alternatively, you could sort your list of `String`s and then use `Data.List.group` and then you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: First write the function `insert1 :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]`. `insert1 x m` inserts x into the list m by creating a new item (x,0) if x is not present in the list, otherwise increasing the count of x by 1.

Answer (score 1):

The bare bones ways to do this is to:

1. Sort the list
2. Accumulate consecutive equal elements into groups.
3. Count the length of each group.

The functions used are `sort` and `group` from `Data.List`:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

An example of how `group` works:

```
group [1,1,1,2,3,3,4]  -> [ [1,1,1], [2], [3,3], [4] ]
```

So now you have to turn a group of equal elements like `[1,1,1]` into the tuple `(1,3)`. I'll leave that for you to figure out.

The complete definition for `freq` will look like:

```
freq :: [String] -> [ (String,Int) ]
freq xs =  map pair (group ( sort xs ))
  where pair = ...(your definition here)...
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, using `Data.Map` :

```
freq :: [String] -> [(String ,Int)]
freq words = toList $ fromListWith (+) [(w, 1) | w <- words]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle might be your friend. You might like to use a function that has the type signature `[a] -> a -> Int`. After hoogeling you will immediately find:

`elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
 base Data.List
 The elemIndices function extends elemIndex, by returning the indices of all elements equal to  the query element, in ascending order.`